# Re-enabling the ability to impersonate External Users via "Log in to Experience as User" button (Spring 21)

Tags: lightning, community, permissions, security

Some Platform Users in my org used to be able to impersonate Community (now "Experience") users from the Contact record by using the "Log in to Community as User" button.

After Spring 21, my Admins can still do this and log in to the Community as the External user, but the non-Admins cannot.

Obviously, I don't want to make everyone a System Admin so that they can log in as External Community Users -- does anyone know what to enable to make this fly?

Comment: Have you granted "Manage External Users" OR "Manage Customer Users" for those non-admin users, see this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_create_external_users.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (this assumes you're logging into the experience from the person account/person contact record). You can also use permission sets to control access to the custom 'Log into experience as user' quick action if you use upgraded dynamic actions in your lightning page layout.

**Apex Controller: LogIntoMemberPortalAsUserCtrl.cls**

```
public without sharing class LogIntoMemberPortalAsUserCtrl {
    public Account acct { get; set; }
    public User portalUser { get; set; }

    /**
     * @description: constructor to set instance variables (acct and portalUser)
     * @param controller (ApexPages.StandardController) : standard controller for Account
     */
    public LogIntoMemberPortalAsUserCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        acct = [SELECT Id, PersonContactId, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :controller.getId()];
        portalUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ContactId = :acct.PersonContactId LIMIT 1];
    }

    /**
     * @description: construct the proxy URL using the data on the Account the 'Log in to Experience as User' button was clicked from
     * @param null
     * @return void
     */
    public PageReference redirectToProxyLink() {
        // Proxy URL example:
        // https://mycompany--companyabc.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.su?oid=00DS0000003Nko2&retURL=%2F0011U00001ttmCx&sunetworkid=0DB1U0000004Fpr&sunetworkuserid=005S000000QZeWF
        Id orgId = [SELECT Id FROM Organization].Id;
        Id memberPortalNetworkId = [SELECT Id FROM Network WHERE Name = 'Name of Experience Site'].Id;
        String proxyURL =
            ApexUtils.subDomainWithProtocol.remove('--c') +
            '.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.su?oid=' +
            orgId +
            '&retURL=%2F' +
            acct.Id +
            '&sunetworkid=' +
            memberPortalNetworkId +
            '&sunetworkuserid=' +
            portalUser.Id;
        PageReference pg = new PageReference(proxyURL);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
}
```

**VF page: LogIntoMemberPortalAsUserPg**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="LogIntoMemberPortalAsUserCtrl" action="{!redirectToProxyLink}">
</apex:page>
```

**Quick Action button**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the setting is "Create and Set Up Experiences"