# Design a button that allows non-admins to login as a community user

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community-builder

I'm trying to create a button that allows non-admins to login as a community user.  It's very similar to the question that was asked in this thread: [Re-enabling the ability to impersonate External Users via "Log in to Experience as User" button (Spring 21)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334584/re-enabling-the-ability-to-impersonate-external-users-via-log-in-to-experience)

I implemented the answer provided by kevdecent, but it only works for admins.  Is there something else that I need to do so this works for non-admins, config or code wise?  My main execution code is below.  The url is returned to the js side of a lwc which then does a window.open() with that url.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String loginSupportUser() {
    Server__c srv = Server__c.getOrgDefaults();
    Id orgId = [SELECT Id FROM Organization].Id;
    Id memberPortalNetworkId = [SELECT Id FROM Network WHERE Name = 'Bank Loan Application'].Id;
    List<Account> docPortalAcct = [SELECT Id, PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Bank Employees For DocPortal' LIMIT 1];

    User portalUser = OpportunityContactRoleController.createCommunityUser(docPortalAcct[0].PersonContactId);

    String proxyURL = srv.Experience_Proxy_URL__c + '/servlet/servlet.su?oid=' + orgId + '&retURL=%2F' + docPortalAcct[0].Id + '&sunetworkid=' + memberPortalNetworkId + '&sunetworkuserid=' + portalUser.Id;

    PageReference pg = new PageReference(proxyURL);

    pg.setRedirect(true);

    // future method call here to update the opp tracking field for last login as support user
    
    return pg.getUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was missing.  The non-admin that is using the button must have the "Manage External Users" check box checked true for app permissions.  This can be done for their profile, or a permission set.